# Calling a non-existent member of a C++ object in QML works "as expected" but why?

Tags: c++, qt, function, qml, qtquick2

I am passing a `QQmlComponent *` to QML as a `QVariant::fromValue(comp)`.

Note that `QQmlComponent` [doesn't have any method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qqmlcomponent-members.html) `createObject()` whatsoever.

And yet in QML this works:

```
qqmlcompPtr.createObject(p)
```

Is the QML engine perhaps doing some implicit conversion in the case of being passed a `QQmlComponent *`? Because that's a method of QML's `Component` element.

I didn't notice this being mentioned in the [article on implicit conversions between C++ and QML](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [QQmlComponent.cpp](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/source/f931ec39513854e56560fe85d55a5d144e22af88:src/qml/qml/qqmlcomponent.cpp#L1041), it really contains a `createObject()` method, but it is a protected method so it could be undocumented.

```
// QQmlComponent.cpp
void QQmlComponent::createObject(QQmlV8Function *args)
{
    Q_D(QQmlComponent);
    Q_ASSERT(d->engine);
    Q_ASSERT(args);
    ...
```

Although it is protected it is also declared as [Q_INVOKABLE](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/source/f931ec39513854e56560fe85d55a5d144e22af88:src/qml/qml/qqmlcomponent.h#L123), hence you can call it from QML. I guess the reason it being a protected method is that it is meant to be called from QML's JavaScript and not from C++.

```
// QQmlComponent.h
protected:
    QQmlComponent(QQmlComponentPrivate &dd, QObject* parent);
    Q_INVOKABLE void createObject(QQmlV8Function *);
    Q_INVOKABLE void incubateObject(QQmlV8Function *);
```

Comment: You appear to be correct, aside from making it sound like Qt is not documenting protected methods, which it is, i.e. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#protected-functions where they are specifically documented. Also a bit ironic making it protected and yet invokable in QML :)

Comment: @user3735658, Okay I rephrased the undocumented part.